# How to prove that we can increase the precision of Riemann sum if we refine a partition

Tags: real-analysis, integer-partitions, riemann-integration

When learning Riemann Integral, I was introduced to the concept of partitions and refining them. It stated that refining a partition (e.g. controlling its norm) increases its efficiency. What I mean by efficiency is the ability to measure the area beneath the curve. My teacher said it's intuitive. But, that's hardly satisfying. 
Also, can anyone give me a rigorous proof (without any graphical methods) of the fact that Riemann sum actually gives the area under a curve?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to ask yourself how to define the area under a curve.

Comment: Yeah... That's something I believe... Just the fact that "area under a curve" is a graphical quantity is what paralyzes us when to try to define it using regular terms...

Comment: It is not too difficult to show that if $P'$ is a refinement of $P$, then $L(f,P')\geq L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P') \leq U(f,P)$ . Intuitively, this means that upon refining our partition, our 'over - approximations' (Upper Riemann Sums) get smaller, and our 'under - approximations' (Lower Riemann Sums) get larger, so they become ' better ' under approximations and 'better ' over approximations for the ' Area under f(x) ' . Again, this assumes a definition of ' Area under f(x) ' .

Comment: But regardless, it does tell you something about what refining your partition really does to Riemann sums.

Comment: Yeah... That's exactly what I tried to do... I did it graphically though... You know, cutting the area in slices and all that... But, my teacher said it was faulty as I could give him some "concrete" proof that the sum actually represents the area under a curve. The exact words, "Drawing graphs won't get you admitted. Try to prove it rigorously." And then after an hour or so, he says it wasn't possible at all... Duh!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the 'Area' of any closed and bounded curve $C$ is $
\iint\limits_C 1\;dx\;dy$ . So when we want to compute the 'Area under a curve' this is equivalent to computing the Riemann integral from a to b of the function that defines the curve. This is one way of defining area, there exist other ways as well.

Comment: Hmm... That's interesting... Thanks for sharing the knowledge... Seems like I'll have to do some reading on the subject...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your "level of sophistication" it is assumed without proof that

(i) all "reasonable" domains in ${\mathbb R}^2$, in particular domains bounded by the $x$-axis, a continuous curve $y=f(x)>0$, and two ordinates $x=a$, $x=b$ have "area";

(ii) rectangles have area $\ell\cdot h$;

(iii) "area" is additive if two domains have at most parts of their boundaries in common; and

(iv) $A\subset B$ implies ${\rm area}(A)\leq{\rm area}(B)$.

These things are dealt with in detail in (geometric) measure theory. *Integration* is about computing the area for domains $A$ of the kind described in (i). Note that there are surprises in store, insofar as domains as simple as a circular disk of radius $1$ can have very strange area values.

Given any partition $P$ of the interval $[a,b]$ the lower and upper sums are areas of unions of rectangles. From the principles (ii)–(iv) it then follows that
$$L(f,P)\leq {\rm area}(A)\leq U(f,P)\ .$$
Exploiting the continuity of $f$ one proves that the lower and the upper sums have a common limit under refinement, and one denotes this limit by $$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\>{\rm d}x\ .$$
A squeeze argument (the lower sums are increasing, the upper sums decreasing under refinement of $P$) then enforces
$$ {\rm area}(A)=\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\>{\rm d}x\ .$$
On the other hand, purely analytic reasoning shows that
$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\>{\rm d}x=F(b)-F(a)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $F$ is any function satisfying $F'=f$. Formula $(1)$ is a great miracle, and is called the fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Yeah... I knew all that... Just the first part... Where you said it's assumed without proof is what I wanted to know... If you can tell me what fields of math I need to exploit in order to get a proof of that, it'll be satisfactory... Math is fun only if I need to devote some man labour...